# Hls media playlist request url override

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, http-headers, http-live-streaming

Trying to implement hls support on my platform build with laravel. Testing both ffmpeg and AWS Elastic transcoder solutions. The problem is that i've got custom url for requesting files for security purposes. That url then returns the hls master playlist, but subsequent request for media playlists  has wrong url. This is because the paths in master playlist are not absolute. I tested it with absolute paths and it worked, but I changed the paths manually, can't see it as an option on AWS Elastic Trancoder, and not tested it yet on ffmpeg package. I'm not really sure what generates the subsequent request for the media playlists? Is it the video player or hls codec/plugin? Can i tinker the original response headers to modify the subsequent requests? Or am I going the wrong way about it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post your code, show us where you are facing the problem.

Comment: the code is not a problem, its the request that is being made when serving hls playlist via custom url. Sorry if i'm not making much sense.